# Linear recursive method for counting palindrome numbers between 2 integers in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm solving a practice problem in Haskell where I'm trying to count the palindrome numbers between 2 given integers. Single-digit numbers are palindromes. I've tried solving it with a helper function but I can't make it take the smaller number from the main function. Any help would be appreciated!
So far I typed this:

```
main :: IO()
main = do
print $ countPalindromes 5 13 == 5 -- 6 7 8 9 11
print $ countPalindromes 13 5 == 5 -- 6 7 8 9 11

rev :: Int -> Int
rev n = helper n 0
where
 helper :: Int -> Int -> Int
 helper 0 result = result
 helper n result = helper (div n 10) (result * 10 + mod n 10)

isPalindrome :: Int -> Bool
isPalindrome x = rev x == x

countPalindromes :: Int -> Int -> Int
countPalindromes a b
  | a > b = helper b a 0
  | otherwise = helper a b 0
  where
      helper :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
      helper a b count
       | a <= b && isPalindrome (a - 1) = count + 1 
       | otherwise = helper (a - 1) b count
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "I can't make it take the smaller number from the main function"? I would also advise you to try some [debugging tricks](https://wiki.haskell.org/Debugging#Printf_and_friends) to get a clearer picture of what is going wrong.

Comment: I mean how to check and set as first argument the smaller from a and b as the helper function must know which is which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not your problem. The problem is that `helper a b count` only returns `count + 1` if `a` is a palindrome, without ever checking if `a + 1`, `a + 2`, etc, are palindromes as well. When the first number is a palindrome, it returns `0 + 1 == 1` and done. (Your definition of `helper` is also counting the wrong way; it's *decrementing* `a` instead of *incrementing* as you need to do if you ever want `a <= b` to be false.)

`helper` needs to recurse whether or not `a` is a palindrome; the only difference is in the value of its *third* argument.

```
helper a b count | a > b = count  -- base
                 | isPalindrome a = helper (a + 1) b (count + 1)
                 | otherwise = helper (a + 1) b count
```

Note that `b` never changes; it doesn't need to be an argument to `helper`. Instead, you can make a recursive call to `countPalindromes` to ensure `a < b`:

```
countPalindromes :: Int -> Int -> Int
countPalindromes a b
  | a > b = countPalindromes b a
  | otherwise = helper a 0
  where
      helper :: Int -> Int -> Int
      helper a count
        | a > b = count  -- base case
        | isPalindrom a = helper (a + 1) (count + 1)
        | otherwise = helper (a + 1) count
```

Tail recursion also isn't terribly important in Haskell. You can write `helper` more naturally

```
helper a | a > b = 0
         | isPalindrome a = 1 + helper (a + 1)
         | otherwise = helper (a + 1)
```

Note, too, that the only difference between `isPalindrome` returning `True` or `False` is whether you add `1` or `0` to the recursive return value. You can capture that with `fromEnum`:

```
helper a | a > b = 0
         | otherwise = (fromEnum (isPalindrome a)) + helper (a + 1)
```

As an exercise, note that you don't need explicit recursion at all.  You can use `filter` to get the values in range that are palindromes, then simply count the number of values in the resulting list.